How to clear DBeaver Cache
Originally, I had these two related tables in my DB:

shared_media - with 8 columns
shared_media_media - with 4 columns

The latter was a bridge table between the shared_media and media tables.
Today, I decided to rename shared_media to shared and then rename shared_media_media to shared_media.  I did all of this in DBeaver on my MacBook.
All is working fine except that in DBeaver, when I click on the Data tab for the new shared_media, I get this error: "SQL Error [42P10]: ERROR: ORDER BY position 7 is not in select list  Position 50"
It also shows me the SQL code it's trying to run: SELECT x.* FROM public.shared_media x ORDER BY 1,7
My supposition is that there appears to be some cached version of the original shared_media (which had 8 columns) and it's using this assumption to run the SELECT against the new 4 column version of the table.
I've tried to do a few things to clear the cache in DBeaver but to no avail.
By the way, this SQL code works perfectly: SELECT * FROM shared_media
Any idea how to fix this?

Does right-clicking the table and choosing "refresh" help?

Unfortunately not.  I tried that, tried restarting the app, even tried clearing the cache via Help > Reset Settings but to no avail.  Not the end of the world but just irritating.

try clicking remove all filters/orderings. It is an eraser icon within the data tab.

Oh wow, that solved it!  Immediately, the error disappeared and the table data was displayed.  Now, to make this permanent - ie. when opening the table in DBeaver again - I had to "Save All Filters".
Thank you for this!
